# What does 'lick' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, literature

> "Well, if that don't lick everything!"

This sentence is from *The Invisible Man*.

The IVM did someting rude and one of the crowd who gathered to confront him said this. If more explanation is needed, I will gradly add more.

Comment: See [lick²](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lick): "overcome" — or, perhaps, ***surpass*** here.

Comment: You should add more details about the context. At first glance it looks like it means the same as “Well, if that doesn't just take the cake!”, which is a more common idiom to indicate outrage at something you find singularly unacceptable. It's akin to saying, “Well, if that isn't just the rudest thing I've seen in a long time!”, but in a less direct manner.

Answer (score 5):

**Lick** in this context means to easily beat or overcome everything. It's considered informal speech, in this case that's illustrated by use of *don't* instead of a more formal *doesn't*.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lick

Answer (score 2):

It is OED, sense 6b of the verb *to lick*.

> 6b To overcome, get the better of; to excel, surpass. it licks me: I
>   cannot explain it. Also to lick into fits: to defeat thoroughly.>
>
> 1800   in Spirit of Public Jrnls. (1801) 4 232   By Dane, Saxon, or
>   Pict We had never been lick'd Had we stuck to the king of the island.
>
> 1836   F. B. Head Let. in S. Smiles Publisher & Friends (1891) II.
>   xxxi. 366,   I believe we shall lick the radicals.
>
> 1847   T. De Quincey Milton v. Southey & Landor in Tait's Edinb. Mag.
>   Apr. 253/2   Greece was..proud..of having licked him [sc. an enemy].
>
> 1879   E. Walford Londoniana I. 37   If we have a war and beat Russia
>   or lick Abyssinia into fits.
>
> 1889   ‘R. Boldrewood’ Robbery under Arms xxiv,   It licked me to
>   think it had been hid away all the time.
>
> 1890   ‘R. Boldrewood’ Colonial Reformer (1891) 195   As a seller of
>   unparalleled generosity, we can't be licked.
>
> 1900   Speaker 8 Sept. 618   We must either lick and rule these
>   savages or run away.
>
> absol. 1861   T. Hughes Tom Brown at Oxf. I. xii. 228,   I believe
>   that a gentleman will always lick in a fair fight.